# Scriptlet error: The method getFullYear()/toLocaleDateString() is undefined for the type Date

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, scriptlet

I am currently trying to use scriptlets to enter the current year or locale date into page title and description like below. On the console, I get the error that is mentioned in the titles, causing the "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP" error.

```
<tiles:param name="pageTitle">something something <%=(new java.util.Date()).getFullYear()%> something something </tiles:param>
<tiles:param name="pageDescription">Last Update: <%=(new java.util.Date()).toLocaleDateString()%>. more something something</tiles:param>
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it? I have imported the java class Date as this at the beginning of the page:

`<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>`

Comment: Those methods are for the JavaScript Date class, the Java Date class is something completely different. Java and JavaScript are entirely different programming languages.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh my god, I have been mixing them! Thank you for pointing this out. It might be a basic thing, but how would I go about to use JS date in these tags? <%=new Date.prototype.getFullYear()%> doesn't seem right either.

Comment: I am not a JSP expert but my understanding is that the code in <%= is Java so you can't use JavaScript there. For Java you would use the java.time classes such as ZonedDateTime, LocalDate...

Answer (score 1):

You can try JSTL for printing date with some formatting.

```
  <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
  
      <c:set var = "now" value = "<% = new java.util.Date()%>" />
      <p>Formatted Date (1): <fmt:formatDate type = "time" value = "${now}" /></p>
      <p>Formatted Date (2): <fmt:formatDate type = "date" value = "${now}" /></p>
      <p>Formatted Date (3): <fmt:formatDate type = "both" value = "${now}" /></p>
      <p>Formatted Date (4): <fmt:formatDate type = "both" dateStyle = "short" timeStyle = "short" value = "${now}" /></p>
      <p>Formatted Date (5): <fmt:formatDate type = "both" dateStyle = "medium" timeStyle = "medium" value = "${now}" /></p>
      <p>Formatted Date (6): <fmt:formatDate type = "both" dateStyle = "long" timeStyle = "long" value = "${now}" /></p>
      <p>Formatted Date (7): <fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" value = "${now}" /></p>
```